# "За" в значении "после"?

Tags: предлоги

Означает ли предлог "за" при упоминании очереди "после" или же "перед" или употребляется в разных случаях в обоих значениях?

*Я буду стоять за Вами.*

Ведь: *за весной следует лето.*

Answer (score 1):

И в том и в другом случае у "за" значение "после": после кого-то встаёшь и после него расплачиваешься, лето наступает после весны.